# What is the difference between Set of Vectors and Sequence of vectors?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

This question was recently asked tn My University's exam on Linear Algebra University Exam When I saw the question I thought I knew it But later I realised that I don't completely understand the difference between them.

Comment: This is not really a question about linear algebra. In general one can ask what is the difference between a set of objects of type $X$ and a sequence of objects of type $X$. This really depends on how you define a sequence. Usually a sequence is a function $\mathbb N\to X$. You could also just say that a sequence is a countable set of objects of type $X$ with a linear order. It is generally a good idea on math.se to show your attempt to the question, for example what you thought the difference was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of vectors is just a subset of a vector space $V$ while a sequence of vectors is a map $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow V$ (can also be written as a infinite tuple). A set does not care about ordering or enumerating elements multiple times in contrast to a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A set is a collection of things in no particular order, with no duplicates allowed. Often the elements are written between braces, so
$$
\{7,2, 3, 5, 3\} = \{2,3,5,7\}.
$$

A sequence is a collection of things in order, with repetitions allowed. It's often written between parentheses, so
$$
(7,2, 3, 5, 3) \ne (2, 3, 3, 5, 7).
$$

You have to be a little more careful with notation for infinite sets and infinite sequences but the idea is the same.

Sometimes people are a little careless when the distinction isn't crucial. If you edit the question to tell us the precise statement of the exam question we can parse it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a set and a sequence differs in two ways:

1. The order among the elements in a sequence is important, while that of the elements in a set is not.
2. An element may be repeated in a sequence, but it does not make sense to repeat an element in a set, because a particular element is either in the set, or not in the set.

For example, consider the sequences $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\dots$, and $1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,\dots$. While the two sequences comprise of the same set of elements $\{1,2,3\}$, they are distinct sequences, because the same elements occur at distinct indices in the two sequences. On the other hand
, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{2,1,3\}$, and $\{1,2,3,3,2,2\}$ are all the same set, because neither the order nor the multiplicities of elements matter for a set.

Answer (score -1):

In a set items cannot appear more than once whereas in a sequence they can. Items in sequences are ranked in order whereas there is no order for sets.